# How do I disable "Activate Task" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, popup

[image: example of the "Activate Task" window]

This window keeps on interrupting me while I am working; it got to a point where I can't even type a single letter. How could I fix or disable this?

Comment: You might learn how to use [Mylyn](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) or consider uninstall it (_Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_). By the way, your Eclipse looks pretty old. Please upgrade.

Comment: I echo the point about upgrading, but you could go to Window->Preferences->Keys to explore key bindings.  You can add text to the filter and/or you can sort by binding. In my Eclipse, "Activate Task" is bound to Ctrl+f9 .

Comment: @howlger I downloaded eclipse from the website a week ago, how is it old?

Comment: @SawLatt Based on icons that were changed several releases ago, it can be said that your Eclipse is pretty old. For details see _Help > About Eclipse IDE_. Old releases are archived, but can still be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

go to Window->Preferences->general->Keys and unbind the activate task option
it will get resolve.